# How to try again if line is failed? c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to try again line if it's failed , until this will be completed & then continue with other code.

1) Do the line (Findelement on the webpage)
2) If this line is failed for some reason - i need to refresh a page & try this line again until it will be completed.
3) Continue

Thank you.

Comment: Show the code and explain better.

Comment: "_How to try again_?" You try a thing again by doing the same thing again. I am aware that this suggestion might perhaps not be overly helpful, but there isn't really any particular and specific information and description about your problem in your question to begin with... (Please read: [ask])

Comment: But when my line is failed , whole app is stopped. So i need to restart this line until this will be completed.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understood your question thoroughly but here is code that might help

```
    do
        {
            try
            {
                // Perform Operation
                break; 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log Error
            }
        } while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

this might even be better for you:

```
private void DoYourThing()
{
    try
    {
        // Do your code here
    }
    catch( Exception _Exception )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( _Exception .Message );
        DoYourThing( ); // Reloop the code if any error happend.
    }
}
```

Comment: This line says error. catch( Exception e )

Something like e is defined , but not used.

Comment: Then your code already contains an e in the same code block, change it to ex or anything